# How to version control multiple forms in one application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a single solution which contains 3 forms so far(will be more in the future).

The first form(main one) is a simple drop down list which shows available applications and opens selected form.

Now, I need to notify a user(on start up of the application) that there is a newer version of specific form available and therefore they should download an updated exe from the LAN.

I could check a folder where all exe files are kept and use exe name but this would only be applicable to the main form.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've read your question a couple of times. When you say "opens selected form", do you mean a separate application (exe)?

Comment: no, form1 will open either form2 or form3 which is in the the same application

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- Maintain each form in a separate class library meaning you can check
  for updated .dll files rather than the exe.
- Publish a text/xml/whatever file with information on the latest
  published versions.
- Just have an assumption that if either of the forms are updated, a
  new exe is required anyway.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I think I will go with the middle one as I want to inform user which form exactly has been updated. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I would use an external XML file or SQL tables to store the applications that can be opened from the main form and their latest (assembly) version number

You could then use a local (user) settings file in the application to pair each application with the last known version and check this against your external file to determine if an update is required.

Then you just need to make sure you change your assembly version number and update your external file whenever you make changes.

Comment: interesting option as well. Will explore both of them but at least have an idea what to do. Cheers